# No logro conectar mi codigo de PHP con la base de datos, un formulario envia los datos a JavaScript y a travez de Ajax y POST los envia a PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, localhost

**Al pasar los datos del HTML al JavaScript, todo correcto este los recibe y puedo trabajar con ellos para implementar Ajax y dentro de el, el metodo POST para asi enviar los datos al PHP descripto aquí abajo, el problema es que al ingresar al PHP este no ingresa al condicional "if" y no ingresa los datos a la base de datos; pero si me permite continuar a la siguiente pagina que estoy programando utilizando el header que se encuentra dentro del "if".**

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
$errorMSG = array();
$registerMSG = "";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $tipo_id = $_POST['id'];
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $nombre2 = $_POST['nombre2'];
    $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
    $apellido2 = $_POST['apellido2'];
    $calle = $_POST['calle'];
    $numero_direccion = $_POST['numero'];
    $esquina = $_POST['esquina'];
    $barrio = $_POST['barrio'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $Contrasena = $_POST['password'];
  try {
            // Consulta para verificar si el email ya está registrado
            $select_email_stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `E-mail` FROM usuario WHERE `E-mail` = 'email'");
            $select_email_stmt->bindParam(":email", $email);
            $select_email_stmt->execute();

            if ($select_email_stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                echo "Error: ";
                $errorMSG[] = "El email ya está registrado";
            } else {
                // Consulta de inserción en la tabla 'cliente'
                $insert_cliente_stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `cliente`(`ID_Cliente`, `Primer_Nombre`, `Segundo_Nombre`, `Primer_Apellido`, `Segundo_Apellido`, `Telefono`, `Numero_Documento`, `Numero_Dirección`, `Calle`, `Esquina`, `Barrio`, `Autorizacion`) VALUES (NULL, :nombre, :nombre2, :apellido, :apellido2, :telefono, :tipo_id, :numero_direccion, :calle, :esquina, :barrio, 1)");
                $insert_cliente_stmt->bindParam(":nombre", $nombre);
                $insert_cliente_stmt->bindParam(":nombre2", $nombre2);
                $insert_cliente_stmt->bindParam(":apellido", $apellido);
                $insert_cliente_stmt->bindParam(":apellido2", $apellido2);
                $insert_cliente_stmt->bindParam(":telefono", $telefono);
                $insert_cliente_stmt->bindParam(":tipo_id", $tipo_id);
                $insert_cliente_stmt->bindParam(":numero_direccion", $numero_direccion);
                $insert_cliente_stmt->bindParam(":calle", $calle);
                $insert_cliente_stmt->bindParam(":esquina", $esquina);
                $insert_cliente_stmt->bindParam(":barrio", $barrio);
                
                $insert_cliente_stmt->execute();
                

                // Obtener el ID_Cliente recién insertado
                $nuevo_id_cliente = $db->lastInsertId();
                echo "Error: ";
                // Consulta de inserción en la tabla 'usuario'
                $insert_user_stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO usuario (ID_Usuario, E-mail, Contraseña, Rol, Tiempo_Conexion) VALUES ('nuevo_id_cliente', 'email', 'Contrasena', '', '')");
                $insert_user_stmt->bindParam(":email", $email);
                $insert_user_stmt->bindParam(":Contrasena", password_hash($Contrasena, PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
                $insert_user_stmt->execute();

                // Obtener el ID_Usuario recién insertado
                $nuevo_id_usuario = $db->lastInsertId();

                // Actualizar el ID_Cliente en la tabla 'usuario'
                $update_user_stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE usuario SET ID_Cliente = 'nuevo_id_cliente' WHERE ID_Usuario = 'nuevo_id_usuario'");
                $update_user_stmt->bindParam(":nuevo_id_cliente", $nuevo_id_cliente);
                $update_user_stmt->bindParam(":nuevo_id_usuario", $nuevo_id_usuario);
                $update_user_stmt->execute();
                echo "Error: ";
                header("Location: ../Controlador/RegisterUsuario.js");
                exit; // Detiene la ejecución del script después de redirigir
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**El código JavaScript con Ajax y metodo POST que utilizo para enviarle los datos al PHP es:**

```
 $.ajax({
                    url: '../PHP/register.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        id:id,
                        nombre:nombre,
                        nombre2:nombre2,
                        apellido:apellido,
                        apellido2:apellido2,
                        calle:calle,
                        numero:numero,
                        esquina:esquina,
                        barrio:barrio,
                        telefono:telefono,
                        email:email,
                        password:password,
                        btnaceptar: true,
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        window.location.href = "../HTML/Login.html";
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        alert("Error, " + error + xhr + status);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que varias de tus consultas preparadas están mal. Cuando usas marcadores de `:nombre` los mismos deben estar precedidos **siempre por los dos puntos `:` y NUNCA deben ir entre comillas, ni simples ni dobles**. Recuerda que son marcadores, no son valores. Revisa por favor los ejemplos en el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php).

Las consultas que deberías corregir son las siguientes:

```
$select_email_stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `E-mail` 
    FROM `usuario` WHERE `E-mail` = :email");
```

---

```
$insert_user_stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `usuario` (`ID_Usuario`, `E-mail`, `Contraseña`, `Rol`, `Tiempo_Conexion`) 
    VALUES 
(:nuevo_id_cliente, :email, :Contrasena, '', '')");
```

---

```
$update_user_stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE `usuario` 
    SET 
`ID_Cliente` = :nuevo_id_cliente 
WHERE `ID_Usuario` = :nuevo_id_usuario");
```

Con esas correcciones debería funcionar, salvo otros errores.

Como recomendación yo evitaría nombrar variables, tablas o columnas usando `ñ`, acentos o carácteres especiales. Si no configuras bien la codificación estos carácteres podrían romper el código. Por otra parte, usar `rowCount()` no es confiable para saber si una consulta del tipo `SELECT` trajo filas, porque depende del buffer. [El Manual de PHP es claro al respecto](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php). Deberías usar un `SELECT COUNT(*)` o verificar los resultados de la consulta en sí mismos.

Finalmente, hacer una redirección desde el servidor en un contexto de petición Ajax no tiene sentido. Lo propio es devolver una respuesta a la petición, y desde ella decidir cualquier cosa, redirección o lo que corresponda. Estás pensando Ajax al estilo viejo, y no es así como funciona. Si tú rediriges, la petición Ajax se queda colgada, huérfana, esperando una respuesta que nunca llega. Vas a tener por tanto un código alocado, desordenado, descentralizado...